# External Hard Drive accidentally turned off and won't show any files

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, diskutil

I recently bought a hard drive and when I connected it to my laptop, the partition option was not available in Disk Utility. So I looked on the Apple Forums and found a solution, which included running the following in Terminal:

```
diskutil erasedisk hfs+ External GPT /dev/disk2
```

I also had my older hard drive plugged into my laptop (it has 5 partitions). I right-clicked and ejected all those 5 partitions from my hard drive and then ran the following in Terminal on my laptop:

```
diskutil erasedisk hfs+ External GPT /dev/disk2
```

I completely forgot to actually unplug my older hard drive from my laptop. As I was intending this to be for my newer hard drive. But then I heard my older hard drive making a sound, I panicked and tuned off the switch on that drive.

Did I loose everything on my older hard drive by doing this?

I have tried to search for a solution but nothing seems to be working.

I do see my older drive show up in Disk Utility as disk as "disk2s2" instead of the names I gave my 5 Partitions and it is greyed out.
When I run

```
diskutil list
```

in Terminal, I see "disk2s2" show up in the list.

The disk was unmounted and ejected successfully using

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

and

```
diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

But it will not mount using

```
diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
```

It returns with

```
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
```

I also tried to run First Aid in Disk Utility but it gives me this message:

```
Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk2s2
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.
Operation failed…
```

[image: This is how it shows up on Disk Utility.]

What else can I try to get my information?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get your disk identifiers?  You reference `disk2` for both your old and new drives.  As for a solution, you need to start looking at things like commercial utilities like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/disk-drill-windows.html)  The key here is to **stop** futzing around with the drive and use a proper recovery utility to attempt to fix it.  The more you mess with it, the less likely you are to recover the data.

Comment: It should be possible to recover partition 2-4 without a problem (as partitions/volumes), partition 5 with minor problems (all with partition/volume recovery). Only the first blocks of the former partition 1 (maybe 300 MB) are probably overwritten/damaged: then file based recovery is required.